# Embedding images from another server - why does it work in Firefox but not Chrome or IE

Tags: php, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm working on a tool that pulls information from a couple of sources - a main server (for data pull), and a voip phone (for screenshot of its screen).  Everything seems to be working fine except for one particularly vexing issue; I can't render the screenshot when the page is shown in Chrome and IE.  In Firefox, it looks fine.

```
<table class="phoneScreen;" border='0'>
        <tr><td><table class="phoneScreen" align=center style="width:95%"><tr><td><img src="http://username:password@<?php echo $ip; ?>/CGI/Screenshot" style="width:100%;"></td></tr>

    </table>
```

This component, http://username:password@ipAddress/CGI/Screenshot, is the main issue.  When I put the link in manually, it works.  But as part of the web page, it doesn't.  The page is rendered through http (not https), so mixed security is not the issue on this page.

Update: In viewing the page with Google Chrome's console, I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" when the page tries to pull the image from the screenshot.  Unusual since when I copy and past that link in another tab it seems to work.

Comment: Need some more information - load the page in IE -> right click and select 'view source' -> get the rendered html and share with us (remove secured information - if any).

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti Here you go, pretty identical to what I posted above <table class="phoneBorder" border='0'><tr><td>

 <table class="phoneScreen;" border='0'>
  <tr><td><table class="phoneScreen" align=center style="width:95%"><tr><td><img src="http://username:password@ipAddress/CGI/Screenshot" style="width:100%;"></td></tr>

 </table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="username:password@ipAddress/CGI/Screenshot"/>
```

This feature is not supported by all browsers and it's not safe as username and password are exposed to the client.

Other option: `<img/>` `src` should be pointing to the same server from where original page is rendered (same origin policy). Get the original image from a different server through server side code using required username and password, send the image back to the client, so that no need to expose username and password to the client.

Comment: Yeah, I started to realize this myself.  However, it presents some new problems because it make grabbing an image a 2-hop process (download to server, send to client).  Doesn't look like there's much choice to do this securely.

Comment: Yes, some overhead is involved.